# Create a delta table in unity catalog using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-unity-catalog

I have a PySpark DataFrame and I want to create it as Delta Table on my unity catalog.

I have the following strucutre:

```
prd
|—- landing
|—- bronze
|—- silver
|—- gold
|—- qa
```

I have my prd catalog with my qa database. My delta table is stored on gold database. So, I loaded it in a DataFrame and I want to create a table in my qa database. I know I can do it using spark sql like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ‘table_name’ 
(
   schema here
) 
using delta
partitioned by(year)
tblproperties (
‘delta.autoOptimize.autoCompact’ = ‘true’,
‘delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite’= ‘true’,
‘delta.feature.allowColumnDefaults’= ‘supported’
)
```

When I run this code, the table is created on `prd.qa`.

My question is:

Is there a way to create that table on `prd.qa` using PySpark? Something like:

`df.write.format(‘delta’).saveAsTable(‘prd.qa.table_name’)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `df.write...saveAsTable`, then you will need to include `.partitionBy` clause as well to force partitioning by a given column, and then you need to set options afterward.

But really, a better way to achieve this is to use the so-called DEEP CLONE ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html), [blog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/09/15/easily-clone-your-delta-lake-for-testing-sharing-and-ml-reproducibility.html)) - it will copy all table options, partitioning, etc. together with data. But the more important is that DEEP CLONE is incremental - if you run it next time, it will copy only new data.  For example, you can execute this SQL command to achieve that:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE prd.qa.table_name
   DEEP CLONE prd.gold.table_name
```